# 3ds max 4 plugin development settings vc6

Tags: c++, plugins, max, 3ds

I am trying to rebuild some old 3ds max plugins for 3ds max 4.2.
The code all compiles but I simply get the ".....dll> failed to initialize" dialogue as max starts up for each and every one of the plugins I am building.

I have read in a few places about needing specific code generation settings espectially regarding memory allocation etc to cope with the differences between release and debug allocation when you build debug versions of the dlls.

All I have found that specifically mentions any particular setting is taking standard debug build settings and switching to "Multithreaded DLL" from the "Debug multithreaded DLL". I can find nothing specific about necessary compiler/code generation settings for anything else.

I am running and building the plugins on a virtual machine running XP and Vc6. I have tried installing the plugins in maxs plugin directory on the virtual machine.
I have tried both release and debug(with the multi-threading change above made) and get the same result.

I have never had anything to do with max plugins before so I guess this is a sort of baptism by fire but if anyone out there knows any gotchas and/or dos and donts I would be extremely grateful.

As an aside I know that these plugins did work once upon a time and I know they are meant for Max 4 sdk as this is referenced in several places already in the projects settings and include paths etc.

Also any advice on how to debug the initialization of the plugins would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance